# Invoke-WebRequest 'ftp' scheme not supported (Powershell >7.0+)

Tags: powershell, ftp, powershell-7.0

I am trying to download a file from ftp but `Invoke-WebRequest` is not working. Since `wget` is not available on Powershell, I have to resort to use `Invoke-WebRequest` but I encountered this error:

```
Invoke-WebRequest ftp://ftp.sanger.ac.uk/pub/users/kp9/demo-vdj.h5ddl
Invoke-WebRequest: The 'ftp' scheme is not supported.
```

How do I resolve this for the latest version of Powershell or is there an equivalent of this to the `wget` command? I'm using Powershell 7.3.7. Thanks.

Comment: I don't believe you can using `Invoke-WebRequest`. Maybe try using the `System.Net.Webclient` class? `$wc=[System.Net.WebClient]::new();$wc.Credentials = [System.Net.NetworkCredential]::new('username','pass');$wc.DownloadFile('ftp://....','C:\Destination\Path.txt')`

Comment: Just found this solution that might: https://techexpert.tips/powershell/powershell-download-files-ftp-server/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error message implies, [`Invoke-WebRequest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest) doesn't support FTP (at least as of PowerShell (Core) 7.3.x, but I'm not aware of any plans to change that).

You can use `curl` instead, which is nowadays also available on Windows.

E.g., to download to file `out.hdf`

```
curl ftp://ftp.sanger.ac.uk/pub/users/kp9/demo-vdj.h5ddl -o out.hdf
```

Note:

- In *Windows PowerShell*, use `curl.exe`, i.e. specify the filename extension *explicitly*, to avoid calling the built-in `curl` *alias*, which (unfortunately) refers to `Invoke-WebRequest`. (This alias has been removed in [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md)).